# I need to introduce an intermediate page before I load the actual page for every request

Tags: spring, freemarker

I've a web application that uses `FreeMarker templates` and tiles to do the View job in the `MVC` world. So upon my request to the application, say `/load.do` I would like to introduce an intermediate page that will have a loader icon just to indicate the page is being loaded on the subsequent request, which is not known to the user.

So ultimately what I'm achieving is a better user experience and also if used within `framework` (the iFrames) this comes handy to show the loader icon when there is a new request that is happening.

Can someone point me to the right method I can use here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using spring mvc.

You need to create something like a WaitController. On user submit , this controller will be called. This can trigger your original request in background and take a reference(UUID) for the call and will render a wait page having the reference id of the original request set in model. Wait page can either trigger immediately the main controller using reference id or can poll the reference id on regular intervals or use web socket to know the availability of results. Once results are ready, it should redirect user to the actual result page.